# How to build cannonball delts without using roids?

Tags: shoulders

So these guys on steroids look like they have these huge 3D capped delts. But I have been told these can only be attained by steroid usage. How are some other ways to get these cannonball delts without substance abuse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the recommended exercise types for getting broad shoulders?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/472/what-are-the-recommended-exercise-types-for-getting-broad-shoulders)

Comment: I think he's looking for the huge deltoids, not so much the lats. A fiction character in a novel described it as a man hiding cantaloupes in his jacket.

Answer (score 1):

Building any body part to its full potential without abusing steroids is hard work.  Unless you’re genetically gifted, you’ve got to be willing to work at it for a long time.  Unlike a steroid abuser, a natural training athlete must optimize all aspects of diet, training, sleep, and nutrition.  And, let’s not forget genetics, a factor you have no control over.  Having said that, if you train consistently, and, with a reachable goal, you should be able to build the body that you want.  You may not achieve "3D deltoids", but, you can certainly improve upon what you have by using exercises that provide a progressive overload to your deltoids, and, target all [three heads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_muscle) of the muscle (anterior, lateral, and posterior).  For example,

- Barbell presses
- Dumbbell side raises
- Bent over dumbbell raises

Answer (score 0):

You can build some with a lot of exercise but definitely not like the ones by steroid users, there's a natural limit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0al_ukv47c0

http://www.builtlean.com/2011/03/30/how-much-muscle-can-you-gain-naturally/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve them by doing machine shoulder press, dumbbell shoulder press, barbell military press, side lateral raises, front raises, and decline flies 3 times a week for 2 years to really get them with a "cannonball" appearance.